# question about notation in HTT of J.Lurie

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-categories

In page 27 in HTT of J.Lurie, the expression
$$\text{Map}_S(X,Y):=Y^X\times_{S^X}\{\phi\}\in \text{Set}_\Delta$$
appears for simplicial set $X,Y,S$ in Warning 1.2.2.2. However, I couldn't understand two notation in this expression, first one is exponential of simplicial set and the second one is product which have lower index. I guess that $X^Y$ is kind of $Hom_{\text{Set}_\Delta}(X,Y)$, but I couldn't be sure about it.

Comment: $Y^X$ is the simplicial set whose $n$-simplices are the maps $X\times\Delta^n\to Y$, that is the internal hom in simplicial sets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just think in terms of ordinary sets for the moment.  We have sets and maps $X\xrightarrow{\phi}S\xleftarrow{\psi}Y$ and we want to think about the set
$$ \text{Map}_S(X,Y) = \{f\colon X\to Y: \psi f=\phi\}. $$
We can think of $f$ as an element of $Y^X$, and composition with $\psi$ gives a map $\psi_*\colon Y^X\to S^X$, and the condition $\psi f=\phi$ can be written as $\psi_*(f)=\phi$, so $\text{Map}_S(X,Y)$ is the preimage under $\psi_*$ of the set $\{\phi\}\subset S^X$.  In other words, the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 \text{Map}_S(X,Y) @>>>\{\phi\} \\
@VVV @VVV \\
 Y^X @>>>  S^X
\end{CD}
is a pullback.  This is the meaning of Lurie's notation.  Everything works in essentially the same way for simplicial sets.